# How I can solve issue with assigning view function to StateObject propety

Tags: swift, swiftui, concurrency, swift-concurrency

I am trying to assign regular function like this

```
var body: some View {
        contentView
        .task {
                navigation.tabBarVisibility = .hidden
                viewModel.fetchWordset()
                synthesizer.onNextUtteranceEnded = onNextUtteranceEnded
            }
}

private func onNextUtteranceEnded(_ utterance: AVSpeechUtterance) {
        guard utterance.voice?.language == "pl-PL" else { return }
        viewModel.next()
}
```

That is defined in swiftui view

To `@StateObject var SpeechSynthesizer`

that has property

```
public final class SpeechSynthesizer: NSObject, ObservableObject, AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate {

    @Published public var isSpeaking = false

    public var onNextUtteranceStarted: ((AVSpeechUtterance) -> Void)?
    public var onNextUtteranceEnded: ((AVSpeechUtterance) -> Void)?
```

But I am getting warning

> Converting function value of type '@MainActor (AVSpeechUtterance) ->
> ()' to '(AVSpeechUtterance) -> Void' loses global actor 'MainActor'

What I can do about it?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by `trying to assign regular function`.
It is best to show a minimal reproducible code, see:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example .  Show the full code and the line that gives you the error.

Comment: I've added more code. I've also tried to add to SpeechSynthesizer @MainActor but it also cuases problems

Comment: good first step, but this is not **a minimal reproducible code**. Note your function `private func onNextUtteranceEnded(_ utterance: AVSpeechUtterance)` needs to return something, like: `private func onNextUtteranceEnded(_ utterance: AVSpeechUtterance) -> xxx`. Whatever `viewModel.next()` is. And the statement `synthesizer.onNextUtteranceEnded = onNextUtteranceEnded()` should includes the `()` at the end.

Comment: It is void it doesn't return anything. And question is that: 
I have function in swiftui View struct like onNextUtteranceEnded that do something. 
But because it is inside view it is on MainActor. Than in onAppear of this view I am trying to assign reference to this function to property in SpeechSynthesizer that is ObservableObject and set up using @StateObject in this view. but it's property seems to be not on the main actor. I doesn't matter that onNextUtteranceEnded() is doing it can be empty

Comment: You are working backwards, the View shouldn't be involved. Why isn't `SpeechSynthesizer` telling the View/Presentationlayer what it needs to show the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `View` is, as you have pointed out, tied to the `@MainActor`. This means that the implementation of `onNextUtteranceEnded` in your view is also tied to the main actor.

`SpeechSynthesizer`'s property doesn't hold any such restriction, so the compiler is telling you that it won't be able to help you out should you happen to call `onNextUtteranceEnded` via the synthesizer from any other actor, you might get yourself in a mess.

The answer is in the warning:

> Converting function value of type '@MainActor (AVSpeechUtterance) -> ()'

This is the type of your view's function

> to '(AVSpeechUtterance) -> ()' loses global actor 'MainActor'

This is the type of `SpeechSynthesizer.onNextUtteranceEnded`

You can remove the warning by changing the definition:

```
public var onNextUtteranceEnded: (@MainActor (AVSpeechUtterance) -> ())?
```

However, as others have pointed out, this does feel like a strange way to do things. You have a state object, that should be making logic decisions internally and updating published properties. The view should just be responding to those changes.

Comment: I have 2 StateObject one is viewModel for specific view and the other is rather general SpeechSynthesizer ObservableObject that is used in multiple places in my app other way probably would be to have it inherited by view models. But there view models are usually marked with @MainActor so you approach is more interesting. I've also found that I can use .onAppear { } instead of .task { }